# Is there a way to get OSX style file previews in the file browser?

Tags: filemanager, interface, previews

In the default file browser of Mac OS X, pressing <kbd>space</kbd> will preview the file in question.

Is there already something similar that I haven't found, or is there a way to add the functionality to Ubuntu?

Comment: I knew some software like this, I forgot their names, though. But I found another one I did not try: http://gloobus.net/gloobus-preview/ I do not post this as an answer since I'm just posting this link without sharing experience or instructions. I hope this fits your needs. Apple calls this feature quicklook, by the way. This may help searching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a program that I think do the thing you asked for (not 100% sure since I never used OSX), it's called sushi.
It basically open a windows giving you preview of all files and directories pressing the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>.
It is in the default repository so to install use can type in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

and you have to restart nautilus:
type in the terminal

```
nautilus -q
```

to close it and click on the home folder icon on the dash to start it again.

Comment: it works, but seems to do some strange things, music and mouse hangs for a second every time I use it

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Gloobus Preview](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html). It works very well and I've been using it for years.