# Which "file browser" is able to open many file types by itself?

Tags: software-recommendation, browser, filemanager

We can use a web browser similar to a file manager, for example use Google Chrome to go to `file:///home/user/`. And web browsers can be used to open many file types like PDF, PNG, MP4, MP3, TXT etc.

Is there a "file browser" that can open such file types internally like a web browser?

Comment: Most Web Browser can be used as "File Browser" (e.g. Firefox, Konqeror, ...) would that be enough ? Many "File Browsers" can at least preview files (Dolphin, etc.). Would that be enough?

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/350510/is-there-a-way-to-get-osx-style-file-previews-in-the-file-browser

Comment: So you want the file manager to open music files, pdf files, and images exactly the way dedicated music players, pdf viewers and image viewers would but without accessing those dedicated applications?

Comment: @pLumo Of the programs you mention, [Konqueror](https://kde.org/applications/internet/org.kde.konqueror), sounds like a particularly good fit for this, since local file browsing/management is among its primary intended uses. I don't currently have a KDE system and I haven't used Konqueror in many years, so I might not be the best person to post an answer about that (at least not without trying it out again first). Would you be interested in posting one?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do something like that with *Nautilus* aka *(GNOME) Files* (default in a vanilla Ubuntu installation). First you need to install the `gnome-sushi` package by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-sushi
```

After installing `gnome-sushi`, you can open files of various types (e.g. image, text, video, pdf, audio etc.) in Nautilus by selecting the file and hitting the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Double Commander has some of such functions
(old nortoncommander clone, but way way better)
maybe this one opens up jpg and images when F3 pressed
also TXT DOC