# How do I get image previews when selecting them in Nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 from scratch after an issue with my old ubuntu installation.

I've found that now it uses GNOME instead of Unity. I like GNOME, but I have a couple of important usability issues that I assume are easily configurable, and I just don't know how to.

One of the main issues is that if I click on an image, the preview won't appear:
[image]

I am talking about the situation where you are in a list view, and click on an image, and it opens an image preview at the side of the list of files, inside the very same Nautilus window.

I tried to search for these issues instead of asking, but I've not found anything that actually got them sorted.

Please note that I've installed GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: The 'preview pane' is a feature of upload/download dialog but I'm not sure whether this future is/was implemented in a standard Nautilus window ever. Refer to this to get quick previews of files in a different way: https://askubuntu.com/q/350510/480481

Comment: You mean like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCJbP.png)?

Comment: :) Yup, exactly like that. I'll look for dolphin @DKBose Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest installing Dolphin on Ubuntu. You may not like the number of dependencies required! Given your needs, I suggest you try something like Xubuntu which gives the user a more traditional desktop.